# Writing an nginx server block to capture wildcard N-level subdomains?

Tags: nginx

I'm running an Nginx proxy server to auto-generate SSL certificates using OpenResty/Lua and LetsEncrypt, within a multi-tenant SAAS platform. I have many domains that need certificates and am not able to whitelist them, so my certificate server accepts all requests that are pointing to it.

I'm starting to see a lot of invalid domain requests coming in that match the domain structure of:

```
www.randomsubdomain.anydomain.com
```

That domain name structure is not valid for my service, so what I'd like to do is create a server block in my nginx config that catches this structure and returns a 444 response, so a certificate is not requested from LE at all.

Here's what I have tested:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^www\.(.+)\.(.+)\.com$;
  return 444;
}
```

Unfortunately, this block does not seem to catch my test domains once I reload the config. My test domain (www.randomsubdomain.anydomain.com) passes through and a certificate is issued, which is not what I want. Is it my regex? I'm far from a PCRE/nginx regex expert, so my regex was constructed using one of the available online testers.

But if I change the server_name to an actual domain name of  "www.test.customdomain.com", the server block catches it and returns the desired 444 response.

I have quite a few server_blocks configured for my app in order to get LetsEncrypt certificates issued, so if it's not my regex, I think one of the other ones is taking precedence, even though I have the above block near the top.

Here's the full block for reference, where app-server.com is my service's domain name. Thanks in advance for any tips/guidance.

```
user ec2-user www;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  lua_shared_dict auto_ssl 100m; #need 1MB per 100 domains in memory
  lua_shared_dict auto_ssl_settings 64k;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;

  init_by_lua_block {
    auto_ssl = (require "resty.auto-ssl").new()
    auto_ssl:set("allow_domain", function(domain)
      return true
    end)

    auto_ssl:init()
  }

  init_worker_by_lua_block {
    auto_ssl:init_worker()
  }

  # Handles SSL app-server.com subdomain requests so they aren't redirected
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.app-server.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://ssl-sites.app-server.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
      auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;

  }

  # Capture SSL requests that already have www and redirect to https://www
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.*;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://ssl-sites.app-server.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
      auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;
  }

  # Capture SSL requests without www and redirect to https://www on subsequent requests once the cert is issued
  server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
      auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;

    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
  }

  # Capture invalid subdomains
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^www\.(.+)\.(.+)\.com$;
    return 444;
  }

  # Capture requests that already have www and redirect to https://www
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.*;
    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # send to challenge if looking for it
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:challenge_server()
      }
    }
  }

# Captures the app-server.com subdomain requests and redirects them
  server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name *.app-server.com;

    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    # send to challenge if looking for it
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:challenge_server()
      }
    }
  }

  # Capture requests without www and redirect to https://www
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    location / {
      return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    }

    # Endpoint used for Let's Encrypt domain validation
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:challenge_server()
      }
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8999;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_max_body_size 128k;

    location / {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:hook_server()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps these requests are HTTPS?

Comment: Reviewing [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) it seems that the wild card domains (e.g. `www.*`) will take precedence over all the regular expression domains.

Comment: Hmm, I think you are right:

...if name matches more than one of the specified variants, e.g. both wildcard name and regular expression match, the first matching variant will be chosen, in the following order of precedence:

1. exact name
2. longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
3. longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
4. first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

Do you know of a way to have the regex be the preferred rule? What if I made it 'default_server'?

Comment: You can try to convert your wild card expressions to regular expressions and have your blocking `server` entry as first in the nginx configuration. I am assuming that nginx tries the regular expressions in `server` block order.

Comment: @Tero. Thanks for that idea. I am trying to come up with a regex to replace the www.* server_name, but it seems to also catch the N-level www subdomains. Assuming the order of precedence is top-down for regex, if the undesired N-level subdomain is caught first, will it stop being processed by other rules later down the config? Might have to try it...

Comment: Try `^www\..+` for as a replacement for `www.*`. With regex, you need to remember the starting anchor, otherwise it is a substring match. You can use https://regexr.com/ to check your regular expressions.

Comment: @Tero I think it's working! I need to do some more testing, but using your regex `~^www\..+$` in place of `www.*` seems to do the trick. I added the `~` to the regex since it seems that is how it is defined wrt nginx, but not sure what it does? Also, do I need the `$` to signify end of line? Thanks again...fingers crossed it passes the rest of my test domains.

Comment: `~` tells nginx to use interpret the next string as regular expression instead of wild card or suffix match.

Comment: @Tero So it seems to be working. Thank you. Not sure how to accept your comment as an answer, though. But I now realize that the domain names I am trying to filter for are actually being created by one of my other rules (adding 'www' to all requests without 'www'). So unfortunately, I need to now figure out a way to catch random subdomains (subdomain.domain.com) and return 444, but allow anydomain.com (without preceding subdomain). I'll post a new question if I need help with that. Hopefully it can be done without 'if'. Again, thanks for your help!